# There is any way to use onCall Firebase functions from an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I understand that firebase cloud functions can be called using the functions.https.onRequest or the functions.https.onCall, but I can't find an example about how use the "onCall" from an angular module, the examples that I found are only with the http request angular module.

example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private http: Http) { }

  postRequest() {
    const url = 'https://your-firebase-project.cloudfunctions.net/secureEndpoint';

    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(authToken => {
              const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken });

              const myUID    = { uid: 'current-user-uid' };    // success 200 response
              const notMyUID = { uid: 'some-other-user-uid' }; // error 403 response

              return this.http.post(url, myUID, { headers: headers }).toPromise()
            })
            .then(res => console.log(res))
    }

}
```

there is any way to use the JS standard call for this on an angular module?

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('FUNCTION');
```

Comment: It's just JavaScript, so should work fine from within Angular too. What's the problem with calling it from your code?

Comment: It should work the same for all JavaScript oriented code running in a browser.  Are you having problems adapting the web samples to your code? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: To be honest, I think that you both are right, but I have the filling that I'm missing something with the angular approach, because yes, I'm trying to adapt my old code from plain JS using <script src> to the angular modular schema, and I can't find examples that do that kind of things, like, edit a ts module and include the src.

Answer (score 1):

I thank you guys for the guidance, you where right, I just use the import in this way:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

and then just call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

This will import **all** the library in the component:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

To import only **functions**, use:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/functions';
```